# Are there Bundle management rights in SDL Tridion 2013 and do they affect content porting of design/schema changes?

Tags: 2013, bundles, content-porter-2013

In our Tridion 2011 security model implementation, design and schema changes are not available to users except for administrators. Hence content porting from Staging to LIVE becomes cumbersome and incurs support overhead.

We are planning to upgrade to Tridion 2013 SP1 and would like to automate some of the content porting prophecies as well. With the introduction of bundles in Tridion 2013, is there a specific **right for bundle management** that could help to overcome the above scenario?

Does content-porter 2013 provide any solution for the above scenario?

I am looking for an OOTB solution without custom code and user impersonation. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tridion 2013 does have a specific bundle management right (per publication, just like the other rights such as page management, component management etc.)

However, I don't think that will help you. Bundles are a type of virtual folder (similar to a search folder) and the items contained within them are regular Tridion items with a location elsewhere in the publication and all of the associated security applied that they would normally have. I think that content porting them as part of a bundle would still require all of those rights that you currently need.

Your question is, in a sense, asking for an OOTB solution to by-passing the OOTB security, which of course is highly unlikely (and if there were some loophole I would expect it to be closed).

I would recommend revising your security model. Most implementations have some form of "Developers" group with write access to a high-level "System" folder within Building Blocks which contains all the Schemas, Templates, TBB etc. underneath it. Author groups do not have access to this folder, but they do have read access to a subfolder that contains the page and component templates which they require in order to apply them to pages and components.

Comment: Thanks David. That's what I am thinking as well but just wanted some expert opinion and confirmation around it.

Comment: I edited my answer to include some best practices regarding the security of schemas & templates etc. Perhaps you could look at moving towards a similar setup?